# drag scrollbar with mouse will stuck, while wheel not

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have 4 identical tables like this, and they were stacked along the "z-axis":

```
TOP_LEFT_FROZEN      |  TOP_FROZEN_HEADERS
------------------------------------------
LEFT_FROZEN_COLUMNS  |  MAIN
```

Each table was set with `overflow: hidden` or something so that only the part that was inside each one's "area" was visible.

If I scroll the MAIN horizontally, LEFT_FROZEN_COLUMNS will stay static, while TOP_FROZEN_HEADERS will be scrolled as well, with `scroll event binding`. And it's similar if I scroll the MAIN vertically.

I have performance issues right now. The largeness of the table it self might be one of the reasons. But what concerns me more is as the title.

If I scroll with the mouse wheel, the scrolling is almost smooth. But if I drag the scroll bar, it dose not respond and won't move until 5 or more seconds later.

What the difference between a mouse wheel scrolling and a drag scrolling?